# Javascript Calculator Issue with Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, calculator

I'm trying to build a proof of concept using an example I came up with to show how we can implement `JavaScript` within `Sharepoint` by building a calculator.

Everything seems to be fine but I'm giving myself a headache trying to figure out why everything is either *undefinied* or `NaN`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function calc (form) {
        var multipliers = [ 0.5, 0.25, 0.10, 0.05, 100, 50 ];
        var bonus;
        var imyindex = form.level.value-1;
        if (form.level.value < 5)
        {
            bonus = (((form.salary.value * multipliers[imyindex]) * form.profit.value) * form.growth.value);
        }
        else bonus = multipliers[imyindex];

        alert (multipliers[imyindex]);
        alert (imyindex);
        alert ("Your bonus is " + bonus);
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<table width="161" border="-1">
  <tr>
    <td width="85%"><form id="form" name="form" method="get" action="">
      <p>
        <label for="level">Level: </label>
        <select name="level" id="level">
          <option value=”1”>A</option>
          <option value=”2”>B</option>
          <option value=”3”>C</option>
          <option value=”4”>D</option>
          <option value=”5”>E</option>
          <option value=”6”>F</option>
          </select>

        </p>
      <p>
        <label for="salary">Salary: </label>
        <input type="text" name="salary" id="salary" />
      </p>

      <p>
        <label for="salary">Profit: </label>
        <input name="profit" type="text" id="profit" value=".25" />
      </p>
      <p>
        <label for="salary">Growth: </label>
        <input name="growth" type="text" id="growth" value=".75" />
      </p>
      <p>
      <center>
      <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="button" Value="Calculate" onClick="calc(this.form)"/>
      </p>
    </form></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: When you click on an input type button, it will submit the form. Try moving the input element after the closing form tag, or use a different element to trigger your function.

Comment: Try using a JS debugger, it will make your life easier, and it will help you find these kinds of problems, Chrome has `Developer Tools`, and Firefox has `Web Console`.

Answer (score 4):

You have smart quotes around your `<option>` values. This is causing the value to be `”1”` rather than just `1`, and that's throwing your calculations way off.

Comment: That was it! I don't know what the heck I was thinking. I actually caught it right before I saw your post. Thanks so much!!

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong type of quotes. Perhaps you are using another text editor which introduced the curly quotes: `”`.

This quotes make the the value selected to be `”1”` rather than `1`, therefore it is being mistakenly being marked as text, and therefore causing `var imyindex = form.level.value-1;` to equal `NaN`.

Replace the curly quotes to double `"` or single `'` quotes, and your problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code : You can't send form as a object to the function on click and the option shouldn't have string value or you could use parseInt to convert them to the integer

```
 otherwise the working example is here live just use :)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ALJ6W/

Answer (score 0):

I'm the developer of software called [Appizy](http://appizy.com) that avoid headaches while creating calculators. Basically it transforms a OpenDocument spreadsheet into HTML+CSS+JS..

You just have to create your calculator on OpenOffice or LibreOffice. Then Appizy turns it instantly into a stand-alone web app.

I hope it can help you to solve your issue !

Best,
Nicolas